# React native AppState not working at released IOS app

Tags: ios, react-native

I use AppState to detect screen lock:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change',nextAppState=>{
            if(nextAppState == 'active'){

            }else if(nextAppState =='inactive'){
                //do something..
                
            }
            console.log("nextAppState     "+nextAppState);
        })

        return ()=>{
            subscription.remove()
        };
    },[]);
```

When building in Debug mode, it works.

But Release mode doesn't work.

I tried some package that detects the screen ([@takeoffmedia/react-native-screen-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@takeoffmedia/react-native-screen-lock)).

It works only on debug mode too.

Does Appstate needs permission for iOS?

I want Appstate to work well in Release mode or I want to know another way to detect screen lock for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it works , But I find a solution to solve it.

1. Make main.jsbundle file

Add script to package.json

```
 `"build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'".
```

then, npm run build:ios

2. Add this file to Xcode .

Project -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources/ Copy Bundle Resources

Add main.jsbundle file to two sections(Compile Sources, Copy Bundle Resources ).

After this two steps, Released App works with AppState.